# How to format DateTime such as "Today at 02:00" or "2 hours ago (14:42)"?

Tags: c#

I need a `c#` method that formats a `DateTime` considering `datetime` from now to the past such as:

```
Today at 14:34
Yesterday at 10:20
2 days ago (02/02/2015 12:43)
Last week (04/01/2015 12:42)
```

I know that I can use the `javascript` plugin `moment.js` but is there any way to do it using `C#`?

Comment: https://github.com/MehdiK/Humanizer#humanize-datetime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it yourself by [subtracting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ysw4sby(v=vs.110).aspx) the two dates, then [formating](http://www.dotnetperls.com/datetime-format) the result and calculating whether it is today, yesterday, last week, 2 days ago and so on...

Answer (score 1):

There is no built in way to do that in .Net Framework.

You need to either write your own code to produce such text or find external library that would do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
Today at 14:34
Yesterday at 10:20
2 days ago (02/02/2015 12:43)
Last week (04/01/2015 12:42)
```

You can format the date and time format using custom DateTime format strings.
The other part you will need to code in your own logic.

[MSDN: Custom DateTime Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
DateTime dd = now;
dd.ToString("HH:mm");
dd.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
```